# My app is not able to build due to com.android.application plugin missing in android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-android-extensions

```
//this is my build.gradle file, plz help.
def var = buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- 
        plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

I tried updating plugins too. It tells that my build configuration is incorrect and anyway I build shows error.[this is config. setting img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfukQ.png)

debug type is set to auto and advanced profiling is enabled.

Comment: Please add/quote the exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Remove following lines from your `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Click on `Try again` available at top

[image: try again]

Comment: already tried and added 3 lines at the end too but problem is same

Comment: @RishabhKumarBhardwaj clean + rebuild. Invalidate cache if necessary

Comment: yes sir I did that too but did not resolved. i searched on other answers as well but could not resolve.

Comment: error comes as soon build starts, I tried rebuild too.

Comment: @RishabhKumarBhardwaj is it the same error? `Could not get unknown property 'android' for task ...`

Comment: how to invalidate cache ?

Comment: `Go to File -> Invalidate caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart`

Comment: error is :   "Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. "

Comment: yes it is project level not module level. first error coming from project level only. invalidating cache too gave same problem

Comment: with updated answer, error is gone but same error appeared in module level gradle file. and If i remove 3 lines from that too, it does not recognics android() method

Comment: @RishabhKumarBhardwaj keep those lines at top and clean and rebuild.

Comment: same prolem. And also see my gradle wrapper properties distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip may it cause problem ?

Comment: I copied and pasted gradle files of both project and module level from a new test project of android studio. Now it worked finally but i may miss something later. but write now this super method is helpful.

Comment: Thats strange. But as long as its working its great! Enjoy coding